# unable to get the exact string from json response using jquery

Tags: json, jquery, jquery-plugins, struts2-jquery

i have a form ,if i submit it then i want the success message to be print from my json response in the same page.

I am getting many values from the json response but i only want the variable called as "message" which i have define in my java action.

***The formated json response is like this***

```
       `{"errmsg":null,"jsonModel":null,"message":"Succussfuyly completed the task","model":
        {"createdDate":null,"createrId":null,"id":null,"themeCaption":null,"themeName":null,
        "themeScreenshot":null,"updateId":null,"updatedDate":null},"oper":null,"theme":{"createdDate":null,
        "createrId":null,"id":null,"themeCaption":null,"themeName":null,"themeScreenshot":null,
        "updateId":null,"updatedDate":null},"themeScreenshot":null}`
```

**From this response i want only the message variable to be printed in my jsp page.
From my below jquery code ,all the value is printing in my jsp page. But i want only messsage variable.**

index.jsp

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready( function() {
        $.subscribe('handleJsonResult', function(event,data) {
            $('#result').html("<div id='languagesList'> <s:property value="Message"/> </div>"+'' + data.Message + '');
            var list = $('#languagesList');
                    $.each(event.originalEvent.data, function(index, value) { 
                            list.append('<h1>'+value+'</h1>\n');
                    });
        });
    });    
        </script>  
        </head>
        <body>

     <img id="indicator" src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/images/others/ajax-loader.gif" alt="Loading..." style="display:none"/>
    <s:form action="updatethemeimageform" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="remoteform"  theme="simple" > 
               <s:hidden value="%{#parameters.themeid}" name="themId"/> 
               <s:file name="themeScreenshot" label="Theme Screenshot" /> 
              <sj:a button="true" id="btnsid" buttonIcon="ui-icon-gear" dataType="json" indicator="indicator"  onSuccessTopics="handleJsonResult" 
              formIds="remoteform" targets="result"  >Submit This Form</sj:a> 
     </s:form>

         <sj:div id="result" >    
            Json Result will come here
         </sj:div>



                       `-----------
                         ---------------
                    private String Message;

           public String updateThemesImage(){ 
    setMessage("Succussfuyly completed the task"); 
    return SUCCESS;
              }
                   ------------
                    -----------
                   With getter & setters`
```

From my above jquery function i am geting output like this  [image: Output of my above jquery function]
please help me to solve this problem

Comment: You'll need to parse that JSON response in whatever function is used for that in JSP tech and output that variable.

Comment: @adityamenon How to do that? This is my first program for json. Can you  please solve my issue

Comment: if JSON is coming fron resource inside the page, why is it being sent as a string in the event data and not an object in the first place? I assume you are converting an object to JSON, then you need to convert it back again rather than consume the original object.

Comment: if the JSON is coming from jQuery AJAX... just add `dataType:'json'`  to AJAX options and response will be converted to object within jQuery core

Comment: @charlietfl could you please post it as answer for my above problem

Comment: would have reslly helped if you detailed what you wanted in question... solution would have been posted within just a few minutes

Comment: @charlietfl yeah, you are right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `each` loop is working correctly however if you only want several specific variables  use object notation to retrieve them:

```
$.subscribe('handleJsonResult', function(event, data) {
    $('#result').html("<div id='languagesList'> <s:property value="Message "/> </div>" + '' + data.Message + '');
    var list = $('#languagesList');

    var jsonData = event.originalEvent.data;
        /* example retrieving ID and message*/
    list.append('<h1>ID:' + jsonData.id + ', Message:' + jsonData.message +'</h1>\n');

});
```

Comment: yeah its automcatically converting my json response into data         (`$.subscribe('handleJsonResult', function(event,data) {`). but from data how can i get the specific variable

Comment: OK...I thought it was already an object...all the `parseJSON ` ideas are off track. Will update answer

Comment: updated... is very unclear in question exactly what it is you want from the data. There are several other approaches depending on what it is specifically you want

Comment: From data i want only message variable

Comment: OK so what I gave you should do it...just remove the ID part

Comment: yeah i got it.  `$('#result').html(event.originalEvent.data.message);`